# How to get a black and white map from ggmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggmap

If I use a state name as the first argument like so:

```
map <- ggmap::get_map("Louisiana", zoom=3, maptype = "toner-background", source="stamen")
```

then I get the black and white map that I want like so:

[image]

But If I enter the first argument with longitude and latitude coordinates like so:

```
map <- ggmap::get_map(c(left=-120, bottom=-65, right=5, top=70), zoom = 3, maptype = "toner-background", source="stamen")
```

Then i always get a map like this:

[image]

The other parameters seem to have no effect.

My goal is to call this function with coordinates like the second line of code and get a black and white map like in the first case.

Comment: I can't replicate this problem with the development version. Have you tried updating ggmap using `devtools::install_github("dkahle/ggmap")`? That has been the fix for all of my ggmap issues.

Answer (score 0):

This issue of getting a Google Terrain map when you wanted a Stamen map is one that I saw recently in another context. Instead of using the generic `get_map` function, try the specific `get_stamenmap` like this:

```
library(ggmap)

ggmap(get_stamenmap(c(left=-120, bottom=-65, right=5, top=70), zoom = 3, 
                    maptype = "toner-background"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've already downloaded the colored images, you have to use `force = TRUE` argument

E.g.,

> map = get_stamenmap(your-map, maptype = "toner-background", color="bw", force=T)